How to configure podman containers memory limits using compose file?
I'm creating containers for my application in my local using podman-compose and I'm not able to configure memory limits.
With podman stats, I'm able to see that the container memory size is always 4.08G irrespective of different configurations I tried.

I have tried following configurations in my compose file,

With deploy resources

 version: "3"
 services:      
   app:        
     volumes:          
       - "..:/app"        
     deploy:          
       resources:            
         limits:              
           cpus: '0.5'              
           memory: 15G            
         reservations:              
           memory: 30G


With annotations

labels: io.containers.resources.memory: 30G


Even creating the containers in command line with --cpus 1.5 --memory 10g also not helping.

I'm using Apple M1 laptop with podman-compose version 1.2.0  and podman version 5.2.4 . So how to configure the containers to be created with varying memory limits using compose file?
